# Resolving a vector into components

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> If $v$ is the vector $i-5j$ and $u$ is the vector $-i+2j$ then resolve $u$ into orthogonal vectors such that $u_1$ is parallel to $v$ and $u_2$ is perpendicular to $v$.

I am pretty sure there's an application of for product but can somebody please tell me how to use here?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:   if you choose $\displaystyle\,u_1 = \frac{\langle u,v \rangle}{|v|^2} \, v\,$ then obviously $\,u_1 \,||\, v\,$, and also $\,\langle u-u_1, v\rangle = 0\,$ so $\,u_2 \perp v\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   To derive the formula from scratch, start with the condition that $\,u_1 \,||\, v \,$, which means that $\,u_1 = \lambda v\,$ for some $\,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\,$. Then write the second condition that $\,u_2 \perp v\ \iff \langle u-u_1, v\rangle = 0$ $\iff \langle u,v\rangle - \lambda \langle v, v\rangle = 0\,$, which gives $\,\lambda = \frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle}=\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{|v|^2}\,$, so $\,u_1 = \frac{\langle u,v \rangle}{|v|^2} \, v\,$ and $\,u_2 = u - u_1\,$.

Comment: that's the projection right?

Comment: where the norm squared is <v,v> ?

Comment: @SakethMalyala Right on both.

Comment: I assume your formula is dot product * unit vector. Can you tell me how to solve this if I were to use the scalar product formula?

Comment: for this problem can we assume that $<x,y>=x_1y_1+x_2y_2....$?, the standard dot product?

Comment: @FaiqRaees $\langle u,v \rangle\,$ *is* the scalar product.

Comment: So if I were to replace the scalar product with the dot product will I create problem? Because the book I have had dot product instead of scalar .

Comment: @FaiqRaees Scalar product and dot product are the same thing, and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Can you please also explain why dot product and scalar product are the same thing? Ones a magnitude second is a vector. How does they represent the same thing?

Comment: @FaiqRaees From [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product): "*In mathematics, the dot product* ***or scalar product*** *is an algebraic operation that takes two equal-length sequences of numbers (usually coordinate vectors) and* ***returns a single number***". Do not confuse the scalar product with the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Comment: wait.. can an inner product return something that isn't a number

Comment: @SakethMalyala Of course not. That was in reply to OP's `second is a vector` comment.